# Format Date output in JSF

Tags: jsf, el, date-formatting

If `#{myBean.birthdate}` is of `java.util.Calendar` or `java.util.Date` type, can I possibly format this inside the EL itself using an existing function perhaps, with the output of like the one produced by the `DateFormat`'s `SHORT`, `MEDIUM`,`LONG` abd `FULL` output type?

Instead of outputting the complete form for the `#{myBean.birthdate}`: **Wed Jan 19 19:01:42 WIT 2011**, I just prefer a simple output of **Jan 19, 2011**.

Should I use `#{formatBean.format(myBean.birthdate)}` instead?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Use [`<f:convertDateTime>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/convertDateTime.html). You can nest this in any input and output component. Pattern rules are same as [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
<h:outputText value="#{someBean.dateField}" >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" />
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: life.java - Jigar Joshi Wow, this is something new for me, very nice ! Thank you ! But what about this following case ? Im using primefaces, and the date value is to be embedded in the attribute value. For example, <p:panel header="searching data for #{myBean.dateField}" ... />.

Comment: @bertie: see my answer below and use OmniFaces.

Comment: how is it possible to check the year or month for example ?

Comment: jmj and @BalusC: Do I understand it correctly that f:convertDateTime is using the timezone OF THE SERVER which may be different from the timezone of THE USER/CLIENT, and thus it can be a DIFFERENT DATE on the computer of the client and the computer of the server, i.e. we end up with WRONG value of type java.util.Date, which is representing a point in time, not a Day-Month-Year triple as is usually the intent of specifying a Date in a web form, please?

Comment: @Palo - it was more than 11 year ago. i don't remember this. It might have changed over time. I don't have a quick setup to test this. You can test this by placing server in different timezone (UTC in docker) and test this out - if you have the setup.

Comment: Thanks. My question is not a quick-hack, get it work somehow (I already got that), but about how are we supposed to use this. JSF can convert user text input containing a date and no time to a java.util.Date object using the f:convertDateTime. Is this a good idea at all, if the Date represents a point in time and if the conversion takes place at the server, it will produce a wrong point in time, i.e. another one than the user at the client intended? Anyway, any idea how to tell the h:inputText to produce a date picker in the browser?

Answer (score 29):

If you use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) you can also use it's EL functions like [`of:formatDate()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Dates) to format `Date` objects. You would use it like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{of:formatDate(someBean.dateField, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm')}" />
```

This way you can not only use it for output but also to pass it on to other JSF components.

Comment: With OmniFaces approach it's more intuitive than the `f:convertDateTime`.

Answer (score 7):

With **EL 2 (Expression Language 2)** you can use this type of construct for your question:

```
    #{formatBean.format(myBean.birthdate)}
```

Or you can add an alternate getter in your bean resulting in

```
    #{myBean.birthdateString}
```

where getBirthdateString returns the proper text representation. Remember to annotate the get method as @Transient if it is an Entity.