# change the date format in jsf

Tags: jsf

I've retrieved data from database and displayed it using

```
<h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
   <h:outputText value=" Date"/>
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{item.date}"></h:outputText>
</h:column>
```

the date here is displayed in YYYY-MM-DD, I want to change it to normal i.e., dd-mm-yyyy format.Can i get any suggestion??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format Date output in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735073/format-date-output-in-jsf)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try a DateTime Converter:

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.date}">
  <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
</h:outputText>
```

See the [Java EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnast.html#bnasv) for detailed information

Comment: Thanq for the answer Handy..dint know that the backing bean property should also be of  type java.util.Date,I's trying with a string type      Once again thanx for quick response