# Cannot convert date type YY correctly to YYYY (Y2K problems)

Tags: datetime, jsf, date, seam

I have a Seam/JSF application that has a date field.

When the user types in `01.01.11`, it interprets it to `01.01.0011` which is obviously incorrect. The correct value should have been `01.01.2011`

Anyone encountered this? How did you solve it? The xhtml is the following:

```
<h:inputText value="#{budgetHandler.grantedFrom}">
  <s:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: O no.y2k...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390663/change-the-date-format-in-jsf. Thought it may be a lil useful, but it seems like yours should work too.

Comment: What if the user types in 01.01.99? Is that 1999 or 2099?

Comment: a time machine! try YYYY.DD.MM just for kicks?

Comment: I don't want YYYY.DD.MM. I want dd.MM.yyyy. Plus, it is the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a Y2K problem. It's just an user error. You asked the user to enter `dd.MM.yyyy`, but the user entered `dd.MM.yy`. It's just represented as last 2 digits of a 4-digit year. The same would happen if the user entered one or three digits as year.

If you fix **your** pattern as `dd.MM.yy`, you'll see that it works for `dd.MM.yy` input as you'd expect.

```
<s:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yy"/>
```

A year of `11` is then interpreted as `2011`, not `1911`. See, no Y2K problem.

If you want to allow both date patterns, I'd suggest to create a custom converter which does the job rightly. You can find a kickoff example in my answer of this question: [how to validate input date against multiple patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952222/how-to-validate-input-date-against-multiple-patterns)

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is a user error. I guess I can wire in some javascript magic to prevent the user from entering yy and only yyyy.