# Display date and time in JSF without milliseconds

Tags: datetime, jsf

I'm getting datetime from my PSQL database in way:

```
2013-06-17 16:07:31.885
```

I'm trying to display it without milliseconds at the end of it, I display them in a way:

```
   <h:outputText value="#{myobj.mydate}">
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"/>
   </h:outputText>
```

I've tried some convertDateTime combinations, but they didn't work out for me. Can you suggest me some solution except brute force string split?

Comment: Are you sure your `Date` value is of type `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `formatDateTime` as above:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myobj.mydate}">
  <f:formatDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
</h:outputText>
```

See the [JSF 2 tld doc](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/index.html) and [JSF 1.2 tld doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/).

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390663/change-the-date-format-in-jsf).