# Displaying the contents of a HashMap which contains Date objects in a dataTable in JSF/PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, hashmap, java-7

I created the following method, which returns a `HashMap<Date, List<Date>>` where the key is a `Date` object and the value is a `List` of `Date` Objects. The method accepts a `List` of `timeStamps` and groups them by day. It then returns those grouped timestamps in the aforementioned `HashMap` construct.

```
 public class GroupDatesByDay {

    HashMap<Date, List<Date>> groupedUserLogins = new HashMap<Date, List<Date>>();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    public HashMap<Date, List<Date>> parseTimeStamps(List<Date> timeStamps) {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
    List<Date> timeStamps = new ArrayList<Date>();

        for (Date ts : timeStamps) {

            cal.setTime(ts);
            cal.set(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            cal.set(cal.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(cal.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(cal.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if (!groupedUserLogins.containsKey(cal.getTime())) {

                groupedUserLogins.put(cal.getTime(), new ArrayList<Date>());
            }
            groupedUserLogins.get(cal.getTime()).add(ts);
        }

        keySet = groupedUserLogins.keySet();
        keyList.addAll(keySet);
        return groupedUserLogins;
    }
}
```

The data within the HashMap should look something like this:

```
Key                          List<Date> 

2018-07-11 
                  2018-07-11 08:14:08.540000 
                  2018-07-11 10:46:23.575000 

2018-07-12  
                  2018-07-12 12:51:48.928000 
                  2018-07-12 13:09:00.701000 
                  2018-07-12 16:04:45.890000 

2018-07-13 
                  2018-07-13 14:14:17.461000
```

In my XHTML, I would like to display this data within a dataTable, and RowExpansion to see the individual timestamps, per day. I have written the following XHTML. As you can see, `userLogins` is what my Java method has returned. I am iterating over it in this `dataTable`, but I don't know how to display the values inside it in the manner described above.

```
<p:dataTable var="userLogin" value="#{userEdit.userLogins}"class="DataTable">
        <p:column headerText=" Recent Logins">
          <h:outputLabel value="#{userLogin}">
          </h:outputLabel>
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4735096/1199132

Comment: I omitted that to make my code look cleaner for StackOverflow. The question is about actually getting those values out of the Hashmap and displaying them.

Comment: You mean you want to iterate over the list? Use `ui:repeat`

Comment: As per this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8552872/2242047 - It's not possible. Please read my question in its entirety. I'm trying to use square-brackets to access  the contents of my HashMap. The dataTable / column construct is already iterating over the values.

Comment: It is possible starting from JSF 2.2. The answer you link to was last modified 7 years ago, so you can't consider it anymore. But you don't mention the JSF impl/version being used. If you're still in JSF 2.0-2.1 I would recommend you to upgrade to 2.2, at least. If not, you can still consider using `Map#entrySet`. You're plenty of choices here.

Comment: We are using PrimeFaces. I listed that as a tag in the original question.

Comment: Primefaces is a JSF component library. You're using JSF too.. Which version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176022/discussion-between-ebony-maw-and-xtreme-biker).

Comment: I know you guys took this offline but don't forget to post your final solution below.  I didn't want to chime in but I typically avoid using Maps in JSF and write wrapper components that expose the map values as Lists.  Just my two cents...

Comment: @Melloware Here you go  - I utilized your recommendation. Answer posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I finally solved it. As suggested by Melloware, I had to involve a List.

**My implementation changed slightly:**

```
private Hashtable<Date, List<Date>> groupedUserLogins = new Hashtable<Date, List<Date>>();
private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
private Set<Date> keySet = new TreeSet<Date>();
private List<Date> keyList = new ArrayList<Date>();
```

...

```
public Hashtable<Date, List<Date>> parseUserLogins(List<UserLogin> userLogins) {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
        List<Date> timeStamps = new ArrayList<Date>();

        for (UserLogin u : userLogins) {
            timeStamps.add(u.getTimeStamp());
        }

        for (Date ts : timeStamps) {

            cal.setTime(ts);
            cal.set(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            cal.set(cal.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(cal.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(cal.MILLISECOND, 0);
            dateFormat.format(ts);

            if (!groupedUserLogins.containsKey(cal.getTime())) {

                groupedUserLogins.put(cal.getTime(), new ArrayList<Date>());
            }
            groupedUserLogins.get(cal.getTime()).add(ts);
        }

        keySet = groupedUserLogins.keySet();
        keyList.addAll(keySet);
        return groupedUserLogins;
    }
```

**My XHTML:**

```
<p:dataTable var="loginDayDate" value="#{userEdit.keyList}"
    sortOrder="descending" sortBy="#{loginDayDate}" class="DataTable">

    <p:column width="15">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText=" Recent Logins" width="110"
        sortBy="#{loginDayDate}">

        <h:outputLabel value="#{loginDayDate}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{Constants.DATE_FORMAT}" />

        </h:outputLabel>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText=" # of Logins" style="text-align : left">
        #{fn:length(userEdit.groupedUserLogins[loginDayDate])}
    </p:column>
    <p:rowExpansion>
        <p:dataTable var="specificDate"
            value="#{userEdit.groupedUserLogins[loginDayDate]}"
            class="DataTable">
            <p:column headerText="Time" style="text-align: left">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{specificDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{Constants.DATETIME_FORMAT}" />
                </h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

**How it looks:**

[image]