# How to output dates using p:calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So i want to display multiple dates in a calendar on my jsf page.
I tried to do it with the `<p:calendar>` but i think its to let the user input dates, but in my case I want to show dates of purchases.

I tried to set the `<p:calendar>` to readOnly and disabled the button clicks but I got serveral problems there. So I can't have multiple dates selected and user can also not use the next month button if I do it like that.

Also I dont really know how I get my dates, which are formatted in like `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` to the Date date formatt which is in millisec since 1900 if I'm not wrong here.

So are their any goto solutions instead of the primefaces calendar because that one is obviously for inputs.

Comment: Then don't use the `p:calendar` to output dates, but a simple `h:outputText`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735073/format-date-output-in-jsf

Comment: @Jasper de Vries yes sure I could simply put it out as text but i want to show it in a calendar view similar to the datepicker of primefaces

Comment: @RobinHoffmann is Schedule what you want? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule/basic.xhtml

Comment: @Melloware have to try to find out, but if its designed for data output it looks like what I was searching for.

Comment: Yep you can make the Schedule editable but you can turn editable=false and use it just for display

Comment: yes thx that one helped me

Comment: Have you tried with readonlyInput="true"?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve:

Using

```
<h:outputText value="#{backingBean.date}">
  <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"/>
</h:outputText>
```

If you still want to use primefaces `p:calendar`, use `readonly` and `readonlyInput` attributes together. Even if it allows to click, it will roll back to previous date.:

```
<p:calendar id="cal"
            value="#{date}"
            pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
            maxdate="#{now}"
            navigator="true"
            yearRange="c-100:c+100"
            readonly="true"
            readonlyInput="true">
  <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
          update="cal"
          global="false"/>
  <p:ajax global="false"
          update="cal"
          event="change"/>
<p:calendar>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the ajax tags? Also, you are simply repeating a comment and an already given answer.

Comment: I tried to give both options in a answer. And I don't see the code in the comment and to use both readonly and readonlyInput in the answer. Do you see it?

Comment: If OP was looking for `h:outputText` it would have been a duplicate.

Comment: @JasperdeVries if such had been the question then I wouldn't have answered.